# Java Files.exists(Path) fails on Linux but passes on Windows

Tags: java, path, filesystems, junit5

So I came across a weird issue (and I dare not say bug as that implies the underlying mechanism for figuring out paths is broken, which I doubt, its probably more my lack of understanding it) but I have a JUnit5 test that Passes on Windows and fails on Linux that started me down this rabbit hole so...

```
   public void testPath() {
    Path test = Paths.get("test");
    Path path = Paths.get("tezt");
    System.out.println(test + ":" + Files.exists(test));
    System.out.println(path + ":" + Files.exists(path));
    System.out.println(test.toAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(test.getFileSystem());
  }
```

(I should point out that the project is a maven project with standard maven directory structure, which I thought might be part of the problem that it was resolving the test directory?)

// path changed to protect the innocent

On Windows the output is: (directory permissions: drwxr-xr-x)

```
test:true
tezt:false
C:\Users\user\pathToProject\directory\test
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem@13b6aecc
```

On Linux the output is: (directory permissions: drwxr-xr-x)

```
test:false
tezt:false
/home/user/pathToProject/directory/test
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem@27ff5d15
```

So the best I can come up with is that it has to do with the underlying the way the file systems are resolving the path? Any help in shedding some light on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't explicitly said whether there is a file called "test" in the current directory.  Also, what happens if you change the file name to something that can't be confused with a directory, such as "testfile.txt"?

Comment: Yea duh... there was a directory that was named test on the Windows side (not sure what generated it as it was on several different development boxes holding on to a database which what the original JUnit test was built for) but it didn't exist on the Linux side. Still investigating what is creating it.

Sometimes the obvious is not so obvious. @Jim Garrison Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

So as @Jim Garrison pointed out there was a directory named "test" in the project directory that was created (at some point) by the unit test which had a temporary database that the unit test was using and didn't clean up after itself properly.

What stumped me as it was on several Windows development machines but not on any of the Linux development machines which I'm still trying to track down what created it and why it didn't clean up but mystery solved.